# Upgrade to linux-image-4.9.0-13-amd64 uninstalled mongoDB

Tags: debian, kernel, apt, upgrade, mongodb

Here's my problem. I'm managing two VM servers under proxmox. Recentry, I upgraded (with `apt update & apt upgrade`) a lot of the VM linux kernels to `linux-image-4.9.0-13-amd64` through the update `linux-image-amd64/oldstable`, now `4.9+80+deb9u11 amd64`.

Distro is Debian :

```
lsb_release -a No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch) Release:        9.13
Codename:       stretch
```

One of the VM has mongoDB on it. Since I did the upgrade and rebooted the machine (all without any errors), mongoDB disappeared (not installed anymore) and I had to reinstall it.

For your information, prior I started managing these servers, an `apt upgrade` has been done on another server, one with `mysql`. Mysql has been uninstalled on it as well after the upgrade...

**My question is : Why, and what can I do to avoid that?**

Here is the end of my `/var/log/apt/history.log` file (for the last seven days) :

```
Start-Date: 2020-07-22  12:00:07
Commandline: apt-get upgrade -y
Upgrade: nodejs:amd64 (10.21.0-1nodesource1, 10.22.0-1nodesource1)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2020-07-22  12:00:14
 
Start-Date: 2020-07-23  12:00:04
Commandline: apt-get upgrade -y
Upgrade: librsvg2-common:amd64 (2.40.16-1+b1, 2.40.21-0+deb9u1), librsvg2-2:amd64 (2.40.16-1+b1, 2.40.21-0+deb9u1)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2020-07-23  12:00:05
 
Start-Date: 2020-07-24  12:00:04
Commandline: apt-get upgrade -y
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2020-07-24  12:00:04
 
Start-Date: 2020-07-27  10:17:29
Commandline: apt upgrade
Install: linux-image-4.9.0-13-amd64:amd64 (4.9.228-1, automatic)
Upgrade: libcomerr2:amd64 (1.43.4-2+deb9u1, 1.43.4-2+deb9u2), e2fsprogs:amd64 (1.43.4-2+deb9u1, 1.43.4-2+deb9u2), e2fslibs:amd64 (1.43.4-2+deb9u1, 1.43.4-2+deb9u2), libss2:amd64 (1.43.4-2+deb9u1, 1.43.4-2+deb9u2), linux-image-amd64:amd64 (4.9+80+deb9u10, 4.9+80+deb9u11)
End-Date: 2020-07-27  10:37:34
```

Below, this is after mongoDB has been reinstalled today :

```
Start-Date: 2020-07-29  11:55:34
Commandline: apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Requested-By: user (1001)
Install: mongodb-org-mongos:amd64 (3.6.19, automatic), mongodb-org-tools:amd64
 (3.6.19, automatic), mongodb-org-shell:amd64 (3.6.19, automatic), mongodb-org:amd64 (3.6.19), mongodb-org-server:amd64 (3.6.19, automatic)
End-Date: 2020-07-29  11:55:50
 
Start-Date: 2020-07-29  12:00:07
Commandline: apt-get upgrade -y
Upgrade: libcurl3:amd64 (7.52.1-5+deb9u10, 7.52.1-5+deb9u11), curl:amd64 (7.52.1-5+deb9u10, 7.52.1-5+deb9u11), libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.52.1-5+deb9u10, 7.52.1-5+deb9u11)
End-Date: 2020-07-29  12:00:09
```

and

```
> dpkg.log | grep remove
```

gives me nothing.

I did a backup of the VM prior to the upgrade so I have the possibility to post files from before the upgrade if needed.

It's my first time using a stackexchange so please excuse me and tell me if I did something wrong on the post !

Any help appreciated to understand this phenomenon !

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I just finished restoring backup and `mongodb` is already not there. Is there anyway I can check when it got uninstalled ? I have an error

```
[26] 12:00:35 R servername Exited with error code 100
```

from a distant server managing the updates on this one. Can it be related ?

**EDIT 2**

```
> zgrep mongodb-org /var/log/apt/history.log.*
```

I found this in `history.log.4.gz`:

```
Start-Date: 2020-03-04  11:47:17
Commandline: apt autoremove
Remove: mongodb-org-mongos:amd64 (3.6.17), sgml-base:amd64 (1.29), libicu64:amd64 (64.1-0.1+0~20190410090943.5+stretch~1.gbp38f694), php7.3-mysql:amd64 (7.3.15-4+0~20200224.55+debian9~1.gbpbea824), mongo-tools:amd64 (3.2.11-1+b2), mongodb-org-shell:amd64 (3.6.17), libtcmalloc-minimal4:amd64 (2.5-2.2), xml-core:amd64 (0.17), libgoogle-perftools4:amd64 (2.5-2.2), libunwind8:amd64 (1.1-4.1), linux-image-4.9.0-8-amd64:amd64 (4.9.144-3.1), libstemmer0d:amd64 (0+svn585-1+b2), mongodb-org-server:amd64 (3.6.17), libyaml-cpp0.5v5:amd64 (0.5.2-4)
End-Date: 2020-03-04  11:47:27
```

So, here's the culprit? Any way I can find who issued the command and why it removed mongoDB while no newer version was installed? No more recent `history.log` files shows any `mongo-db` activity. Strange thing is that it would seem no user noticed any problem until today? Any chance the reboot I did after kernel update did that? Something about a cache somewhere maybe?

Comment: If you check the backup, does it really show the `mongodb-org` package is installed?

Comment: Backup finished restoring, I could just check it. You're right, mongodb-org is already not there. I edited my post with this new info. Thanks !

Comment: OK, so the MongoDB removal is unrelated to the kernel upgrade. Does `zgrep mongodb-org /var/log/apt/history.log.*` show anything relevant?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I found the culprit with the zgrep. I just have one last question (post edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we determined in comments, the removal of MongoDB isn’t related to the kernel upgrade. The logs at the end of your question,

```
Commandline: apt autoremove
```

show that *most* of the MongoDB packages were removed because they had been installed automatically but were no longer needed. This is probably because they were installed as dependencies of `mongodb-org`, and the latter was subsequently removed. The removal of `mongodb-org` would have happened by March 4 and no longer appears in the logs.

As far as noticing the change, I suspect that the key factor is the reboot. A Debian policy-compliant package would stop its service on removal, but this might not be the case for the MongoDB packages (which don’t come from Debian). So the packages were removed in March, but the service continued running and serving data; it only stopped when the server was rebooted.

Comment: Case closed. Thanks a lot for your help !